# Simple Harmonic Motion - An odd system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

In the following system, we know that:

- $m_a = m_c = 0.2 kg$
- $m_b = 0.8 kg$
- $k = 200 N/m$

[image: System]

After $m_a$ falls on $m_b$ (assuming an inelastic collision), the system will perform small oscillations. We want to prove that the **amplitude** for such vertical movement is $0.125 m$

---

The problem here is that the tension changes the behaviour of the system. I've tried a conservation of energy approach, by saying that:

The kinetic energy of $m_a + m_b$ after the collision plus its gravitational potential energy (the height corresponds to the initial equilibrium position) plus the ellastic potential energy (again, considering the initial deformation) are equal to the final gravitational potential energy (the new height is related to the amplitude) plus the ellastic potential energy (also related with the amplitude).

So, since we don't know $L$, I can't calculate the variation of $m_c$'s height nor the new equillibrium position. What should I do?

Comment: Did you read the whole question? I've assumed that it was an **inelastic collision.**

Comment: Please note that this site is not a place to obtain solutions to worked problems. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/25301) and [this Meta post for "check my work problems"](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/25301).

Answer (score 1):

You may just assume that L is much greater than any other relevant lengths, so $m_c$ does not really matter.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, but the result I've found is critically over 0.125m. There something else that we should consider in order to find the correct result.

Comment: @N.H.Deutschland : I am not supposed to solve your problem, sorry.

Comment: -1 How do you know that you can assume that $L$ is much greater than the amplitude of oscillation?

Comment: **sammy gerbil:** The original question remarks that we should use this approximation.


          **akhneteli:** I know that you don't have to solve it! I was just asking for another solution methods.

Comment: @N.H.Deutschland If the original question told you to use this approximation, then why does your question end by stating that, since you don't know $L$ you cannot do the calculation? What role does $m_c$ play in this problem? Why do you say that *the tension changes the behaviour of the system*? How does it do that?

Comment: @sammygerbil: According to the OP, "the system will perform small oscillations".

Comment: Note that the distance from $m_b$ to the pulley $m_c$ will oscillate up and down by a distance $\sqrt{x^2 + L^2} \approx L + x^2/(2L)$.  This means that $m_c$ will oscillate by this amount as well, which adds another quadratic term to the potential energy of the system, affecting its frequency (and therefore the amplitude of the oscillations.)  But to find this contribution, you'd need to know $L$.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert : You probably meant "the distance from $m_b$ to the pulley $m_c$ will oscillate up and down by a distance" $\sqrt{x^2+L^2}-L\approx x^2/(2L)$. As "the system will perform small oscillations", according to the OP, we perhaps can assume that $x^2/L<<x$ and $m_c$ is significantly less than $m_a+m_b$, so the gravity energy term for $m_c$ is negligible compared to that for $m_a+m_b$.